# how to update gridview that make up of multiple table into the database?

Tags: database, gridview, rows

i have a gridview, i not sure how to code for updating row of a gridview that is make up of the 4 table and retrieve them and update them each new value to it respective database table?

so in the back end code how should call it in rowupdating

the database make up the gridview is make up of 4 different table

which mean this code in aspx

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource4" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Proj %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT image.img, style.styleName, Card.CardName, Card.CardID, Card.price, backViewImg.backViewImg FROM backViewImg INNER JOIN Card ON backViewImg.backViewImgID = Card.backViewImgID INNER JOIN image ON Card.imgID = image.imgID INNER JOIN style ON Card.styleID = style.styleID">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using procedure for update command and pass binded columns as parameter

Comment: can you show me an example of what you mean? cause i not get what you mean..plus i first time updating multiple table in a datagridview

Comment: UpdateCommand="your stored procedure name"     UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure"

Comment: ...sry about i dont know what procedure mean? so i think may be your example can be more clearer?

Comment: Stored Procedure is a set of sql statements that are grouped together.  Google for Stored Procedures and you will get lot of working examples.

Comment: yes in the procedure you write those update statements. you can write multiple update statements, insert statements within a procedure, and pass binded grid values as parameters